# Is it possible to grab camera property values using ipropertybag?

Tags: c++, camera, directshow

Basically what I want to know is if its possible to grab certain camera properties using the ipropertybag. It seems like

```
    CComPtr< IPropertyBag > pBag;
    hr = pM->BindToStorage( 0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void**) &pBag );
    if( hr != S_OK )
        continue;

    // ask for the english-readable name
    //
    CComVariant var;
    var.vt = VT_BSTR;
    hr = pBag->Read( L"FriendlyName", &var, NULL );
    if( hr != S_OK )
        continue;
```

This is grabbing the Friendly name of the camera and I was wondering if its possible to grab other property values like gain, offset x and y, and what not using this property bag.

Answer (score 2):

The properties available there are documented in [Selecting a Capture Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566) article:

```
"FriendlyName"  The name of the device. VT_BSTR
"Description"   A description of the device.    VT_BSTR
"DevicePath"    A unique string that identifies the device. (Video capture devices only.)   VT_BSTR
"WaveInID"  The identifier for an audio capture device. (Audio capture devices only.)   VT_I4
```

Additional properties can be available if the respective driver prepared certain registry keys, however this is a rare case. In any event reading properties maps to reading from registry, which means those are static values unlike runtime parameters you were interested in. Values like gain are queried using respective filter/pin interfaces.